# cpコマンドでコピー元、コピー先が同じディレクトリの場合

Tags: linux

カレントディレクトリとは別の場所にあるファイル、例えば `httpd.conf` のバックアップ(.bk)を取りたい時、コピー元とコピー先が同じディレクトリの場合にコマンド入力を省略する方法はありますか？

新人に何で出来ないのと言われて、もしかして出来るのでは？と思ってしまいました。

```
cp -p /usr/local/src/httpd.conf /usr/local/src/httpd.conf.bk
```

ちなみに以下のコマンドだと、カレントディレクトリにバックアップが取られます (当たり前だと思いますが)。

```
cp -p /usr/local/src/httpd.conf httpd.conf.bk
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
cp -p /usr/local/src/httpd.conf{,.bk}
```

で多分いけると思います。 cp の機能ではなく、シェル(bash) の機能を使ってます。

Comment: 出来ることを確認しました！！　ちなみに、{}は初めてみたのですが、シェルの何という機能になりますか？？

Comment: @Eiji  brace expansion です。